# How to voice command a music player?

Tags: music, music-player, voice-command

I would like to know if is that possible to voice command music actions, like **next track**, and even **delete track** would be very nice.

My sport, rowing, doesn't allow me to interact with smartphone through hands, so, these voice commands would be extremely helpful.

In my tries, I just found **listen to**, which is not that interesting.

*I am using Android 2.3.7 - Cyanogenmod 7.2 for Defy*

Comment: I don't think this is ever going to be possible because the music is going to interfere with the speech recognition.

Comment: The idea is to play music over headphones

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with your stock player.

After some digging I found a good app for you. It's called [Voice Action Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hackedcube.vampLite&hl=en)

See if this suits for you.